# I continue getting an error whenever I run my Django program

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, syntax-error

I started building an application using Django but whenever I run it I always get this error message.

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is p
robably caused by a circular import.

I currently have three files:

mysite/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^account/', include('accounts.urls'))
```

accounts/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
]
```

and views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Home page')
```

This should theoretically print "Home page" on my ip but the error message continues arising in cmd when I run : python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
(I cd'd it too)

This is a simplified version of my hierarchy:

```
Mysite
  accounts
    urls.py
    views.py
  mysite
    urls.py
```

I have been following a tutorial and checked that everything is correct.

Can someone help me find a solution? 
*(Please don't beat me up if I messed something very obvious up. I am new and quite inexperienced)*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please _don't remove_ your comments when you change your question. Your code looks fine and should run without error, make sure you have saved everything (and also check my comment replying to your _removed_ comment).

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo:

try changing `urlpatters` to `urlpatterns` in your "accounts/urls.py".

Comment: and in your "mysite/urls.py", did you close the `urlpatterns` list? Although that shouldn't be the issue here. Also make sure your accounts app is included in your settings.